# iPhone in-app purchase: receipt verification

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have a few doubts about transaction receipt verifications:

- why is an external server necessary? Why can't I just contact http://buy.itunes.apple.com directly from the iPhone?
- what if this external server is down, or the receipt is not valid? How to communicate it to the payment queue? `finishTransaction` would still show a 'payment succeeded' alert view, because the transaction was actually successful, and I guess this would confuse users.

Sorry if I misunderstood the in-App Purchase flow or my questions aren't clear enough. Thanks.

**Edit:** I guess I shouldn't call `finishTransaction` if I find out the receipt is not valid, but is this a problem? The documentation says the application should always call that function. Also, at that point the money has already been transferred... *confused*

Comment: Have you called Apple? This is something you should verify with them. Alternatively, you can submit your app as you *think* it should be. Leave review notes and then the review team will get back to you with the results of the review. Write a detailed explanation of your question in the review notes.

Comment: @Moshe: I thought this may be a common problem. What others who have already implemented in-App purchase do when a receipt is invalid?

Comment: I don't know. I've never done in app purchase. I was just suggesting what I would do. I have starred this question. I may be implementing in-app purchases soon and I want to know whatanswers you get. Also, does a test account require a credit card, or just an email address? Best of luck!

Comment: @Moshe: just an email address. No money needs to be transferred. And thanks for the answers anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Receipt validation ensures that the transaction is complete and successful. You don't want to do that from the iPhone because you can't really trust the user's phone.

1. The user initiates an in-app purchase
2. When complete, the app asks your server for validation
3. You validate the receipt with Apple: if it's valid, you can perform whatever action linked to the purchase (unlock/deliver content, register subscription...)
4. The app removes the transaction from the queue (`finishTransaction`)

If the server is down, you shouldn't finish the transaction, but display an "unavailability message" to the user.

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

will be called again later.

**But** if you find out that a receipt is invalid, you should finish the associated transaction. If not, you may have extra-transactions living forever in the transaction queue. That means that each time your app runs, `paymentQueue:updatedTransaction:` will be called once per transaction...

In my apps, receipt validation is done through a web service, returning an error code in case of an invalid receipt. That's why an external server is needed. If a user somehow manages to skip receipt validation (by faking the web service "success" response), he won't be able to unlock the content / access functionality because the server has no trace of the purchase.

Comment: - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions is actually called, but the transaction.transactionState is "SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed" and transaction.error.code is SKErrorPaymentCancelled.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add that if the user can't be trusted, you can't assume that they have not also faked communication with your server on a closed network. ie: unless you are using something similar to a SSL certificate, you can not be sure that your server validation came from your server and not his Mac.