# should I call finishTransaction when serverside receipt verification fails?

Tags: ios, storekit

I use server side receipt verification.

When client's

`- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
 updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions`

is called, and `transactionState` is `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`,
client sends the receipt to our server,
and our server verifies it.

When the server side receipt verification succeeds,
client obviously calls `finishTransaction`, no problem.

When the server side receipt verification failed,
because apple temporary returned non json, or client sent invalid receipt, or something,
server returns that information to client.

Next, what should our client do?
Should we call `finishTransaction`?

This leads to invalid transactions living forever in the queue?
like said in this question: [iPhone in-app purchase: receipt verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863497/iphone-in-app-purchase-receipt-verification)

> But if you find out that a receipt is invalid, you should finish the associated transaction. If not, you may have extra-transactions living forever in the transaction queue. That means that each time your app runs, paymentQueue:updatedTransaction: will be called once per transaction...

But if we do `finishTransaction`, our precious user is charged by this receipt (which we failed to verify), right?

Or does the verify-failed-transaction expires in some period?

Is this documented somewhere in apple's document?
I couldn't find any in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to finishTransaction.

It's up to you if you give the user what they want then. In some cases it's better to give the user what they want, even if the receipt is invalid or fake (using jailbreak). Especially when it costs you nothing.

Comment: I see this comment frequently about just providing the content anyway if the receipt fails.  If you plan on doing that, why go through the trouble of validating the receipt at all?  Just curious about your opinion on that.

Comment: @Scooter one reason could be to identify problem users, e.g. you could keep track of the number of failed receipts for every user in your database. You would then be able to spot suspicious behaviour and take necessary actions. Or at least monitor how "corrupt" your user base has become. Maybe we just have to accept there will always be a small number of dishonest people and weigh up whether or not it's making a serious dent on our income stream.

Answer (score 2):

I finish the transaction to clear it from the queue, but don't provide the extra content if the validation fails.  If it is an invalid receipt then they were not charged by Apple.  If it turns out to be something else, such as Apple's verification server being temporarily down, then they will have been charged and when they attempt to restore purchases (or add it again) they won't get charged again, and your app will get another shot at verifying the receipt.

If the verification fails for a technical reason such as Apple's server being down it will be awkward, but there is no other way that I can see to prevent someone from stealing your content.  The good news is that you can let the user know in a popup if Apple's server is down and that they should try again later and most importantly that they won't be charged again.

Comment: You need to watch out for an empty in_app array when using consumable products.  If the in_app is empty you can use SKReceiptRefreshRequest to get another copy of the receipt to check if the purchase is in there, but if it is a consumable, it won't be.  From Apple: "Information about consumable products is added to the receipt when they are paid for and remains in the receipt until you finish the transaction. After you finish the transaction, this information is removed the next time the receipt is updated. Thus resulting in an empty in_app array if your app only sells consumable products"